# Why do humans lose subcutaneous fat from the extremities with age?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-physiology, fat-metabolism, fitness

Why does fat tissue die and shrink on the hands, knees, and lower legs of most people as they age, even when they are overweight?
In most people, their bone definition becomes much more visible around their extremities.

I'm aware I asked a similar question before, but the previous question wasn't specific enough.
[Why do humans lose subcutaneous fat tissue with age?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76884/why-do-humans-lose-subcutaneous-fat-tissue-with-age)

With age, humans store more visceral fat because of multiple factors that include physical inactivity, higher FSH levels, androgens, a drop in estrogen in women, and other factors.

Comment: what makes you think they do?

Comment: Bones of the extremities become much more visible with age. The bones of the upper face also become much more visible. Its very apparent on the back of the hands, the feet,and outter sides of the knees.

Comment: Are you sure that is not just due to  a loss of skin tone.

Comment: It doesn't happen to everyone.  Skin by itself is very thin without any subcutaneous fat underneath it. People do lose fat in these areas with age.